# How can I get the return value of a Laravel chunk?

Tags: php, laravel

Here's an over-simplified example that doesn't work for me. How (using this method, I know there are better ways if I were actually wanting this specific result), can I get the total number of users?

```
User::chunk(200, function($users)
{
   return count($users);
});
```

This returns NULL. Any idea how I can get a return value from the chunk function?

Edit:

Here might be a better example:

```
$processed_users = DB::table('users')->chunk(200, function($users)
{
   // Do something with this batch of users. Now I'd like to keep track of how many I processed. Perhaps this is a background command that runs on a scheduled task.
   $processed_users = count($users);
   return $processed_users;
});
echo $processed_users; // returns null
```

Comment: Wait, you want to get the total number of users, you don't need any data back from that? Doesn't seem like chunk would be the most effective way to do that

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'm trying to get the results of the chunk function. Please ignore the specifics of the example.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I added another example.

Comment: Hmm. I've tried it against my own model and I experienced a similar issue. I wonder why. I suppose you could always query the count of all users first, and then paginate your query, but that seems like what chunk should do. +1. Let's see if anyone else knows.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy RJ Lohan's method worked. Kinda cool. Thank you for your troubleshooting as well!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve what you want in this way. The anonymous function is invoked by the chunk method, so anything you return from your closure is being swallowed by `chunk`. Since `chunk` potentially invokes this anonymous function N times, it makes no sense for it to return anything back from the closures it invokes.

*However* you can provide access to a method-scoped variable to the closure, and allow the closure to write to that value, which will let you indirectly return results. You do this with the `use` keyword, and make sure to pass the method-scoped variable in *by reference*, which is achieved with the `&` modifier.

This will work for example;

```
$count = 0;
DB::table('users')->chunk(200, function($users) use (&$count)
{
    Log::debug(count($users)); // will log the current iterations count
    $count = $count + count($users); // will write the total count to our method var
});
Log::debug($count); // will log the total count of records
```

Comment: If you need more fine control, you can also use a property of your class, (in your example, $this->count), and increment it in the chunk's closure.

Comment: For those who find this is not working for them, for me the count would reset every chunk loop. I forgot to add the `&` paramter to the `use` statement. If you add that it will work properly.

Answer (score 4):

```
$regions = array();

Regions::chunk(10, function($users) use (&$regions ) {

    $stickers = array();

    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        $user->sababu = ($user->region_id > 1)? $user->region_id : 0 ;
        $regions[] = $user;
    }

});

echo json_encode($regions);
```

Comment: The $stickers array is not being used, it should be removed to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Use this custom function to get return value from chunked data

```
function iterateRecords($qb, int $count = 15)
{
    $page = 1;

    do {
        $results = $qb->forPage($page, $count)->get();
        $countResults = $results->count();

        if ($countResults == 0) {
            break;
        }

        foreach ($results as $row) {
            yield $row;
        }

        unset($results);
        $page++;
    } while ($countResults == $count);
}
```

How to use it

```
$qb = User::select(); 
$users = iterateRecords($qb, 100);
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->id;
}
```

Total Users Count `$totalUsersCount = $qb->count();`