# Return data from anonymous function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, anonymous-function, maatwebsite-excel

Using `Maatwebsite` to upload an Excel file to the database.

Every row has a property type, for example 'penthouse' or 'villa'.

I want to gather every property type of every row.

Using the following function won't work:

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->load($csv->getRealPath())->chunk(250, function ($results) {
    DB::table('prices')->truncate();

    foreach ($results as $row) {
        /**
         * @var CellCollection $row
         */

        array_push($this->property_types, $row->property_type);

        $price = Price::create($row->all());
    }
});
```

With defining `$this->property_types` in the `__construct` function like:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

    $this->property_types = [];
}
```

This will result in an empty array.

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026795/how-can-i-get-the-return-value-of-a-laravel-chunk#answer-26027060), defining the array and `using` an ampersand might fix the problem although this will return the same result, an empty array.

```
$data = [];

Excel::filter('chunk')->load($csv->getRealPath())->chunk(250, function ($results) use (&$data) {
    DB::table('prices')->truncate();


    foreach ($results as $row) {
        /**
         * @var CellCollection $row
         */

        array_push($data, $row->property_type);

        $price = Price::create($row->all());
    }
});
```

What do I have to do to define data inside an anonymous function, and retrieve the data outside the function?

Comment: Which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: `Return data from anonymous function` then `return $something;` in the anonymous function;)

Comment: And `$this->` points to witch Instance??

Comment: Are the prices added to the database correctly?

Comment: No need for `uses (&$data)` ('uses' must be 'use', if used), just create the array within the function and add `return $data;` at the end of the function.

Comment: what about using array($this, "functionName") instead of anonymous function. That you'll get the existing function called and you can avoid all the tricks with anonymous function

Comment: Does it work if you pass in `false` as the third parameter to `chunk()`? For example `->chunk(250, function ($results) use (&$data) { /* your code */ }, false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, by default, the `chunk()` method will process your anonymous function asynchronously inside of a queue. Since the function is being run by a worker inside a queue, you won't have synchronous access to any of the data it processes in the code that calls the `chunk()` method.

You can prevent the use of the queue by passing in `false` as the third parameter to the `chunk()` method.

```
Excel::filter('chunk')
    ->load($csv->getRealPath())
    ->chunk(250, function ($results) {
        /* your code */
    }, false);
```

---

As an additional side note, you're calling `truncate()` inside your callback. I don't know if this was intentional, but this will truncate your table on every processed chunk.

Comment: Works perfectly, and indeed, thanks for the comment about the `truncate()` function.